# Infinite Non-abelian group with every non-identity has infinite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any infinite Non-abelian group whose every non-identity element has infinite order?

Comment: Take the free group generated by two non-commuting elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions from reals to reals of the form $f(x)=mx+b$ with $m>0$.

$f(g(x))=m(nx+c)+b = mnx + (mc+b)$ and $mn > 0$ and the other requirements are equally simple to check.

Comment: Example is quite nice. Can you give some insight to prove no element has finite order except identity .

Comment: The slopes are multiplicative, so the slope of $f^N$ is $m^N$, and thus if $f$ has order $N$, then $m^N=1$ which implies $m=1$. That means $f(x)=x+b$, in which case $f^N(x)=x+Nb$ which can only be the identity function if $b=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For instance, the so-called *free group on two elements* $F_2$.

It consists of all finite words (including the empty word) using the four letters $a,b,a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, where the group operation is word concatenation, and with the obvious inverse cancelling (e.g. $abb^{-1}a=aa$).

This is, in some sense, the "most general" group generated with two elements, in the sense that given any group $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ generated by two elements, there is a unique homomorphism $F_2\to G$ that maps $a\mapsto x,b\mapsto y$.

For those interested in algebraic topology, this is the fundamental group of the figure-8.

Comment: You can, of course, use more than two generators, and make larger free groups. The free group on a single element is (isomorphic to) the integers with addition.

Comment: It's maybe intuitive but not entirely obvious that $F_2$ has no torsion so you should say something about this. E.g. it follows from the fact (also not entirely obvious) that subgroups of free groups are free.